# How to get messages sent by members in a group using the Telegram Bot API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to receive messages sent by group members using Telegram Bot API, I'm using `getUpdates` to get messages but only getting command `/command` messages, the rest of the normal messages are not received by bot ok i want to receive all messages to check if the user sent message contains offensive words and delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bot needs to be added as admin to a group chat to have access to all user messages.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to list all users then? My bot is already a Admin. If it's not too much for you, i asked a similar question about 10min ago and if you can please answer i would be grateful... :)